# What's the suitable diagram for system runtime behaviors?

Tags: uml, diagram

I am trying describe the **runtime behaviors** of a system. The system is a desktop application written mostly in Java. It is composed of multiple threads communicating with each other in the background and a GUI for user interaction.

I can draw some informal illustrations. But it's better to take **a formal approach**. Please advise. Thanks.

### Update 1

Just found this [4+1 architectural view model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%2B1_architectural_view_model). Seems helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a UML approach, you'll want to look at an Activity diagram.  (If your system encompasses multiple use cases, use one activity diagram for each.)  If you want to diagram each behavior separately, use sequence diagrams for each single thread of behavior.  If you are more concerned with the different states that your behavior passes through, use Statechart diagrams.